# Confused about Java Layouts

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm not very experienced with Java Swing Layouts. I'd like to make a layout looking like the one in the picture. Is there any easy way to understand and create layouts?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXeTn.png]

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Idea

Comment: Are you using a plugin (GUI Builder) or all by code?

Comment: If you searched, you would have found the Oracle Java website which is full of such tutorials with fully working code examples.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Learn the basics of each layout manager. Then the trick is the you can nest panels with different layout manager to achieve your desired layout. We can't give an solution because a picture doesn't give layout requirements. For example what happens when the frame is resized horizontally or vertically? Which components grow/shrink?

Comment: Just a rough hint: It looks like it could be a pane with `BorderLayout`. The `JTextField` could be in the `SOUTH`, and in the `CENTER` there could be another panel. This other panel could have a `BorderLayout` as well, with one `JTextPane` in the `EAST` and one in the `WEST`, and one in the `SOUTH`. (Assembling this with some `JSplitPane` objects might bring greater flexibility, though...)

Answer (score 1):

There are tutorials on the oracle website and there are wysiwyg layout-building tools that show you interactively what you are building. One of them I have personally used in the past is the Window Builder you can get as an eclipse plugin but it is by no means the only one.

In the end though what it comes down to is experience. Fool around with them, try them out, get to know them. If you dont code with them yourself it is difficult to understand them properly.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know GUI builders existed. I'll use those.

Comment: @P3NG00, Don't use a GUI builder. The code can't be maintained on other IDE's if you ever switch. You spend more time learning the IDE. Spend you time learning Swing and the knowledge is portable no matter what IDE you use to help compile/debug.

Comment: What are you referring to? The Window Builder plugin for eclipse produces comparatively clean and very much readable java source code. It can easily be used across IDE's like any hand written code could. These are great tools to play around with when starting out with a new library.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any easy way to understand and create layouts?

I cannot judge what others would find easy, but my approach to laying out containers is to look for **sub-sections** of the GUI that would be easily done with a particular layout, then working outwards from that.

For example, it seems a single row `GridLayout` might be well suited to displaying the top two text panes. Then the rest of the GUI can be created by placing the panel with the two text panes into the `PAGE_START` constraint of a `BorderLayout`, with the third text pane in the `CENTER` and the text field in the `PAGE_END`.

Done.

[image]